# Zeitdauern in Synthesevorschriften mit "für" oder ohne?

Tags: preposition, time

Ich bin gebeten worden, eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit zu korrigieren, in der regelmäßig Zeitdauern im Rahmen von Synthesevorschriften angegeben sind. Die Autorin schreibt z. B.

> Dabei wird zunächst Schwefel 10-12 h auf 230 °C erhitzt...

Ich empfinde das als vergleichsweise schlecht lesbar, tlw. sogar verwirrend. Mein Korrekturvorschlag:

> Dabei wird zunächst Schwefel **für** 10-12 h auf 230 °C erhitzt...

Die Autorin lehnt diesen Vorschlag ab, "weil vor Zeitangaben keine Präposition steht", konnte mir dazu aber auf die Schnelle keine Quelle liefern. Ich habe ebenfalls keine Quelle für beide Vorschläge finden können.

Welche von beiden Varianten ist nun richtig? Gibt es eine dritte (bessere)? Wie würdet ihr in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten Zeitdauern beschreiben?

Comment: Ich würde die Variante der Autorin wählen. "für 10-12h" hört sich nach Anglizismus an. Eher "über 10-12h", wenn eine Präpositon muss

Answer (score 5):

Vermutlich gibt es Konventionen für solche Anweisungen, und die Autorin wird damit vertraut sei, ebenso wie die Zielgruppe. Daher ist es gut möglich, dass diese die Formulierung nicht verwirrend finden.

Unabhängig davon wird der Satz meiner Meinung nach nicht besser, wenn man "für" einfügt, es hört sich an, als sei das aus dem Englischen übersetzt.

Eher würde ich schreiben

> Dabei wird zunächst Schwefel 10-12 h **lang** auf 230 °C erhitzt

Was für mich aus dieser Formulierung nicht klar wird, ist, ob der Schwefel innerhalb von 10-12 h langsam bis 230 °C erhitzt wird, oder ob er schnell erhitzt wird und dann 10-12 h heiß gehalten wird (vor sich hin köchelt). Aber möglicherweise weiß die Zielgruppe, dass nur eine dieser beiden Varianten sinnvoll ist.

Comment: Ich würde vermuten, der Unterschied zwischen langsamem Erhitzen und Vor-Sich-Hinköcheln würde sich äußern in "Schwefel wird *über 10-12 h bis auf ... erhitzt* vs. *Schwefel wird 10-12 h auf .... erhitzt*.

Comment: Das "default" Temperaturprogramm ist hier wie beim Plätzchenbacken: Ofen auf 230 °C vorheizen, Schwefel rein und 10 - 12 h backen :-) Alles, was komplizierter (oder empflindlicher) ist, muss beschrieben werden. Ich hab in meiner Antwort ein bisschen das drumrum erläutert.

Answer (score 4):

Ich hätte dazu ja gern meine Fußballfreunde befragt, aber bei denen stand es **nach** 90 Minuten immer noch 0:0 und sie mußten **für** eine weitere halbe Stunde aufs Spielfeld und konnten mir nicht helfen. Hättest Du die Frage doch bloß **vor** 10 Uhr geschrieben, da wären sie noch in der Kabine gewesen.

Auf der anderen Seite sehe ich allerdings auch nicht, was dich an:

> Dabei wird zunächst Schwefel 10-12 h auf 230 °C erhitzt...

genau stört. Ich habe *einige Minuten* nachgedacht und bin zu keinem Schluß gekommen - wenigstens zu keinem, den ich durch Nachdenken *für* 10-12 h hätte entkräften können. *10-12 h Nachdenken (des Nachdenkens)* hätten auch nicht mehr zutage gefördert, als die Erkenntnis, daß Präpositionen vor Zeitangaben durchaus zulässig, aber keinesfalls immer notwendig sind.

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin zwar analytischer Chemiker und habe seit meinem Studium keine deutschsprachigen Synthesevorschriften mehr gelesen, finde aber nichts Ungewöhnliches an der Formulierung.

- "Schwefel 10-12 h auf 230 °C erhitzen" bedeutet in Langform: Ofen auf 230 °C stellen (wenn die Zeitangabe ± 1h erlaubt, ist vorheizen gute Praxis, aber eher nicht erforderlich), Schwefel in geeignetem Tiegel hinein, nach 10 - 12 h herausholen.

  - Wenn ein genaueres Temperaturprogramm erforderlich wäre, dann müsste das detailliert beschrieben sein.
  - Wenn wichtig wäre, dass der Schwefel schnell auf 230 °C gebracht wird, müsste das ebenfalls angegeben sein.
  - Die Vorschrift klingt für mich nach einer klassischen [*Darstellung* (4.)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Darstellung) von [polymerem Schwefel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwefel#Polymerer_Schwefel).
- Möglicherweise wurde die übliche, aber vielleicht etwas altertümliche Zeitangabe "über Nacht" durch 10 - 12 h ersetzt.

---

- In der Küche gibt's ähnliche Formulierungen: "Teig 15 min ruhen lassen"
- Und im Alltag muss ich vielleicht "3 min auf den Bus warten"

Answer (score 1):

Die Synthesevorschrift

- Dabei wird zunächst Schwefel 10-12 h auf 230 °C erhitzt

ist völlig klar. Formulierungen wie

- Dabei wird zunächst Schwefel für 10-12 h auf 230 °C erhitzt
- Dabei wird zunächst Schwefel 10-12 h lang auf 230 °C erhitzt

klingen zwar gefälliger, allerdings gibt es mit Sicherheit im Rahmen chemischer Synthesevorschriften einen etablierten Sprachgebrauch, über den man sich nicht hinwegsetzen sollte. Fachsprachen sind eben nicht am Wohlklang orientiert, sondern an Kürze und Prägnanz. Und ehrlich gesagt: Einen echten Mehrwert hat die Hinzufügug von "für" oder "lang" nicht.

Der gleiche Sprachgebrauch ist im Übrigen jedem vertraut, der schon einmal ein Koch- oder Backrezept verwendet hat. Hier sind einige Beispiele:

- Den Teig in die Form füllen, glatt streichen und den Kuchen 50-55 Minuten im unteren Ofendrittel backen.
- ... Knochen hineingeben und 3 Min. bei mittlerer Hitze anrösten. Zwiebel und Gemüse dazugeben und alles weitere 3 Min. rösten. Tomatenmark dazugeben und unter Rühren 3 Min. braten. Mit 100 ml Fond ablöschen, 1 Min. einkochen lassen. Den übrigen Fond dazugießen und aufkochen lassen, das Sauerbratengewürz einstreuen. Fleisch einlegen und abdeckt im Ofen (Mitte, Umluft 140°) 45 Min. garen. Dann den Braten wenden und noch 1 Std. 45 Min. garen, dabei nach 1 Std. immer wieder mal wenden. Zum Schluss den Deckel abnehmen und den Braten 15 Min. offen weitergaren, sodass die Oberseite noch etwas Farbe bekommt.

Answer (score 0):

Bei Zeitdauern läßt man doch häufig eine Spezifikation weg: Die Sonne scheint 12 Stunden am Tag. Nur am Satzanfang setzt man etwas ein: Nach 3 Stunden Aufenthalt... In Fachzeitschriften wird jedes überflüssige Wort gespart, schliesslich muß man sich an den page charges orientieren. In diesem konkreten Fall ist "für" ein Anglizismus, denn man erhitzt ja nicht zugunsten der 12 Stunden.